# Profile shows employer

Tags: support, profile-page

For some reason, my profile has started to show my work title (it may have been for months, I have removed it now). I don't remember setting it - would there be some kind of LinkedIn integration that would have done this by default?

This account is using the same personal email as my LinkedIn account while my Stack Overflow account associated with my pro email has no mention of my employer.

Comment: Stack Exchange has no LinkedIn integration.  Have you perhaps filled out title within your [Developer Story?](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1429487)